# VB.Net 2010 / SQL Server 2012 - Populate Treeview with hierarchyid data (Winforms)

Tags: vb.net-2010, hierarchical-data

I'm looking for a flexible way to populate a treeview in a WinForms application with data from a SQL Server 2012 database.  Here's the structure of the data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCommodity](
    [CommodityNode] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
    [CommodityLevel]  AS ([CommodityNode].[GetLevel]()),
    [CommodityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CommodityName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CommodityDesc] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DTCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [DTUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [tinyint] NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [tinyint] NULL,
    [RecStatus] [bit] NULL)
```

There are an unlimited number of hierarchy levels and so the routine needs to be flexible enough to handle many levels.

I've seen some other examples (all C#) and I just can't seem to follow what is happening.  Is there a simple way to read the hierarchyid data and create the tree directly from that?